# How to define/use CBaseVideoRenderer-constructor

Tags: c++, directx, directshow, c++builder

I want to use the C++-Class CBaseVideoRenderer. Which file do I need to include to get its constructor?

I have included renbase.h, but there's only the declaration. I have included strmbase.h and any other errors regarding this class vanished but the one for the missing constructor.
renbase.cpp seems to have a constructor but I cannot just include it without errors.

So, do you know which files I need?
Im Using embarcadero's C++-Builder from XE2 16.

**EDIT:** I want to use this class:

```
CBitmapRenderer::CBitmapRenderer(
    TCHAR *pName,
    LPUNKNOWN pUnk,
    HRESULT *phr
)
    : CBaseVideoRenderer(CLSID_BitmapRenderer,pName,pUnk,phr)
    , m_InputPin(NAME("Video Pin"),this,&m_InterfaceLock,phr,L"Input")
{...
```

With this code:

```
CBitmapRenderer *m_pSnapshotter = new CBitmapRenderer( _T("Bitmap renderer"), NULL, &hr );
```

Which leads to an Link-error:

```
[ILINK32 Fehler] Error: Nicht auflösbares externes 'CBaseVideoRenderer::CBaseVideoRenderer(_GUID&, wchar_t *, IUnknown *, long *)' referenziert von C:\USERS\JULIAN\DESKTOP\PROGRAMM\WIN32\DEBUG\TESTRAUSCHEN.OBJ
```

That I know comes from a missing definition for the constructor.

**EDIT2:**

I have now included all files within baseClasses-direcory and the compiling is sucessful(without errors). However, when I try to run the application, I get the message "strmbase.dll" is missing. Install this program again"
But I never had a strmbasd.dll. I have a strmbasd.lib. That's the result when trying to compile the baseclasses-project with visual studio in debug-Mode.

Does anybody knows where to get this dll or how to use the lib instead?

Regards,

Julian

Comment: You need to show the code(*the code you have written, the definitions of classes you are using*), post the exact error you are getting, and tell what you are trying to achieve..without this information there is little anyone can do to help you.

Comment: @Als : Thanks, I tried to make it a bit more clear according to your tipps.

Comment: You should have referenced the first episode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902410/linkerror-not-resolvable-link-error-without-using-these-types

Comment: @RomanR.: well, it isn't really a first episode, as it seems that many agreed that it was a really useless post... So I tried to make another one more clearly with the real problem pointed out... Well, I guess I'm unable to post my question just right^^

Comment: You cannot build the binary because `CBaseVideoRenderer::CBaseVideoRenderer` is not available. And this is not your code, it is code from DirectShow BaseClasses. So you need either of the two: (a) additionally link to `strmbase.lib` (`strmbasd.lib` in Debug), or (b) include BaseClasses files with missing functions onto your project.

Comment: @RomanR. well, I include strmbase.lib already via menu->add file, or what do you mean? I tried now just to add every file (.cpp&.h) that was inside the directshow-baseclasses-directory and it is kind of slow to compile now with 2mio codelines... well... compilation and linking sucessful, but when trying to run, it says it can't find "strmbasd.dll" which I also seem to cannot find...